# How can I add peer (on my laptop) to the IBM Bluemix blockchain (hyperledger)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, peer

I am trying to add a peer (my local laptop) to the IBM Bluemix blockchain using docker-compose and using an existing peer's address + discovery port (30001), but it hangs on startup with this as the last message:

`transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken EOF`

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
vp5:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.0-preview
  ports:
  - "7050:7050"
  - "7051:7051"
  - "7052:7052"
  environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=WARN
  - CORE_PEER_ID=vp5
  - CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=dcc56501d31b435ea8898c9e1ad10982-vp1.us.blockchain.ibm.com:30001
  - CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=noops
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  command: peer node start
```

What needs to be changed?

Comment: Does the Bluemix hyperledger expose member services credentials that would allow an additional peer to join? If it did, you would need to provide those via environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are using a Bluemix Starter Plan Blockchain service which is based on Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1.  The fact that the peer image noted is labeled x86_64-0.6.0-preview is why I assume that you are using the blockchain service based on Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1.  To restate the question, can a local peer be added to a four-peer blockchain network running on Bluemix (Starter Plan utilizing Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1)?

When using a Bluemix Starter Plan blockchain network, a local peer that is running outside of Bluemix cannot be added.  The whole blockchain network is hosted on Bluemix and has four peers.

There is a High Security Business Network vNext Beta which is based on Hyperledger Fabric version 1.0.  When using this new beta service, it is possible to invite participants to a blockchain network and those participants can create peers.  This all happens within the Bluemix service, so a local peer cannot necessarily be added.  However, the High Security Business Network vNext Beta makes it possible for multiple entities to join a blockchain network and then a peer is created for each participant that joins.  A comparison of Bluemix plans is available [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/index.html).